# Is there a way to enable smooth scrolling for PDFs?

Tags: laptop, pdf, evince, overlay-scrollbars

There is one small issue with Ubuntu that is driving me crazy. Smooth scrolling when reading documents PDF's isn't smooth. I was using evince to read PDF's and bigger books of 200+ pages. The slightest movement results in a major movement of many pages.

So, I blamed evince and the installed xpdf but no, its the same thing. Is there anything i can install/fix to allow smooth scrolling when I read documents?

In LXDE or KDE, the PDF viewer has the little up and down scroll arrows in the bottom right corner.

Is there anyway to enable these for laptops so we aren't "pulling" at the documents and can scroll PDF's smoothly on laptop's?

Answer (score 5):

Try holding alt when pressing the arrow keys.

Found it out today.

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu 12.04 smooth scrolling is enabled system-wide and many GTK3 applications (most of the default ones) support it. However, the default PDF viewer, Evince, does not yet.

The good news is that smooth scrolling in Evince might be coming as an update. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/981248.

Also, if you disable overlay scrollbars, scrolling with the touchpad over the regular scrollbar will make the document scroll smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

Well unfortunately I cannot find anyway to directly fix the problem with the overlay scroll bars.

But have found a way to remove them so reading PDF's would again be possible.
revert to the default scrollbars`echo "export LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0" | sudo tee /etc/X11/Xsession.d/80overlayscrollbars > /dev/null`

Found the solution here on  [Disable Overlay Scrollbars in Ubuntu Natty  - TuxGarage](https://web.archive.org/web/20200513043103/http://www.tuxgarage.com/2011/04/disable-overlay-scrollbars-in-ubuntu.html)

Answer (score 1):

I find that opening the PDFs into Firefox (yes, **the web browser**) allows one to read them with smoothscroll. I have been unable to find a native/dedicated pdf viewer application for Ubuntu that does this.

I also found that I could solve Firefox's jerky smooth scroll by disabling all speedstep/power-saving related options in my BIOS.

**Alternatives**

If you hold down the middle mouse button and drag up/down, then that is a way to scroll smoothly. However, unlike with Firefox, you have to worry about the fact that you are not locked on the x-axis if you are zoomed in such that the margins do not show. The same effect can be realized by using Okular and just click-dragging rather than using the middle mouse button. This feels more natural.